# Cannot access Lightning Data Service API

Tags: rest-api, lds

[image: Localhost Preview]

I want to use LDS record forms but cannot not access the api .
Error message - Unauthorized access .

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Could you please provide more detail in your question; just [edit] to add some code snippets showing how you are using the API and to explain what you have set up for local development etc. As the question stands there's a high chance it won't get answered since you haven't provided any detail. Take a look at [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) for further information.

Comment: Have you tried opening localhost in your browser and approve the warning message you should get since you're on http?